# Can someone help me the ways to write a correct config file for list of servers in linux. I'm manually making the config file for my script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, redhat

I'm writing a script that will log in on to each server and will take some data from a file and then it will put the data on a local system file. For security reasons, I'm don't mentioning the all details about servers in the same script (in variable array). I just need to know the ways to write the config file. tell me all the ways to write the config for the same.I wrote like:

host_config file has :

```
Host 1(what name I write here)
  Hostname xyz
  User user1
  IdentityFile /path/of/pem/file
  ServerAliveInterval 220

Host 2(what name I write here)
  Hostname lmn
  User user2
  IdentityFile /path/of/pem/file
  ServerAliveInterval 220
...
...
10
```

My script is as :

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./hosts_config
while read ${Hosts}
  if ssh -i ~/.pem/test.pem  ${User}@${Hostname} == True
  then
    echo "Jenkins login successfull."
    ls
  else
    echo "Failed to login to jenkins"
  fi
done
```

Comment: What's in `hosts_config`? What is your actual question?

Comment: I need to know how can I write the config because this host_config doesn't work. I need to know all the ways to write the config file for any shell script which contains much information about servers.

Comment: `ssh -i ~/.pem/test.pem  ${User}@${Hostname} == True` attempts to run the command `==` with the argument `True` on the remote server. Unless you have installed a command with that name which does something useful, this is pretty much guaranteed to fail.

Comment: So are you _actually_ trying to ask how to extract the `Host` lines from your config file...?

Comment: Your `hosts_config` looks like you're trying to make an SSH config. If so, you don't need to _source_ it in your script, look into this guide: https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/

Comment: that's correct. I need to access all the Host from the host_config and their underneath  variables

Comment: If the file is indented like in your example, you could do `sed -n 's/^Host //p' host_config | while read -r host _; do if ssh -i "$host" true </dev/null; then `...

Comment: I'm sorry @sfphoton I don't want to write anything in ~/.ssh/config. I'm making a user-defined config for my script with their own config file.

Comment: @tripleee `Muster` really makes a lot more sense. Who would cut `mustard`? If that was from my comment that I deleted, thanks for that :)

Comment: Ok so forget about host_config, can somone tell me the other way or the fine way to write  a config file I have a list of servers which has below details.

    server IP
    server timeout time
    username
    pemfile
    port
I have same info for more than 10 servers

Comment: @GouravSaini you can specify custom config files for SSH as a parameter: `ssh -F /path/to/hosts_config`.

Comment: Perhaps consider storing the config in json and parsing it with `jq`. There's a good [Q&A here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477210/looping-through-json-array-in-shell-script) on unix.stackexchange.com Where the accepted answer does something similar to what are after. Personally when I think "config" anymore, I think "yaml" and the format of `yaml` is similar to your config file, however, the only parser I can find for the command line is a `pip` package called `yq` which looks like it's just a wrapper for `jq`. So.. might as well cut out the middle man if you head this route.

Comment: @JNevill Historically, the phrases are "pass muster" and "cut the mustard".

Comment: @jhnc It looks like you are right. That being said, I **CAN** imagine passing mustard, but I can **NOT** imagine cutting it. Or rather, I could imagine cutting it, but I can't imagine why one would. I'm just going to avoid both phrases.

Comment: Don't write `if cmd == True`, just write `if cmd; then ...`.  eg `if ssh user@host cmd; then`.  The `if` checks the return status of the command.  If the command returns 0, the `if` branch is executed.  If not, the `else` branch (or nothing).

Comment: No one has mentioned ... you can't just `source ./hosts_config` — that will try to _execute_ the contents of the file, and those aren't commands that can be executed. You will have to _read_ and _parse_ the file, and rather than go to all that trouble I think @JNevill's suggestion to use json is a good one (upvoted)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment:

There are a million ways to skin this cat. Based on the way you were aiming to write your shell script (looping through hosts in a config), you may want to consider a more standardized and structured markup language like `json` for the file, for which we have command line program `jq` which is built to parse json files. Using json as a config file format is also more portable since most modern languages can deal with json natively if you want to move this out of shell.

Consider a config file like:

```
> cat host_config                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
{
  "hosts": {
      "Host1": {
          "Hostname":"xyz",
          "User":"user1",
          "IdentityFile":"/path/of/pem/file",
          "ServerAliveInterval":"220"
      },
      "Host2": {
          "Hostname":"abc",
          "User":"user2",
          "IdentityFile":"/path/of/pem/file2",
          "ServerAliveInterval":"300"
      }
  }
}
```

Then your shell script will take the form:

```
#!/bin/bash
for host in $(jq '.hosts | keys | .[]' host_config); do
    user=$(jq ".hosts.${host}.User" host_config)
    hostname=$(jq ".hosts.${host}.Hostname" host_config)
    identityfile=$(jq ".hosts.${host}.IdentityFile" host_config)
    serveraliveinterval=$(jq ".hosts.${host}.ServerAliveInterval" host_config)

    echo "The host ${host} has name ${hostname} for user ${user}, identity file ${identityfile}, and server keep alive interval ${serveraliveinterval}"
done
```

---

```
The host "Host1" has name "xyz" for user "user1", identity file "/path/of/pem/file", and server keep alive interval "220"
The host "Host2" has name "abc" for user "user2", identity file "/path/of/pem/file2", and server keep alive interval "300"
```

Comment: what does first line says in script.. for host in $(...  ??please explain it

Comment: This is using a program called `jq` that you will have to install on your machine. It's a command line program that is very popular. It can parse json formatted data. That line says `jq '.hosts | keys | .[]' host_config` which tells `jq` to open `host_config` and parse it. Starting at the root of the json object `.` find the array called `hosts` and return from that all of the keys `Host1` and `Host2`. The `| .[]` bit at the end just gets those keys out of the array format so they are strings.

Comment: Then the `for host in $(<previous command>); do` iterates through each host key `Host1` and `Host2` and sticks it in the `host` bash variable. That variable is then used inside of the loop to pull in the attributes in the json file for each host key. It's a little odd feeling if you haven't worked with json before.

Comment: One other thing that may help if you search the internet trying to understand `jq` or `json` better, The string that we feed to `jq` like `'.hosts.HOST1.User'` is called a "json path". The "path" describes the location of an item in the json object. We give `jq` a file and a json path and it returns what it finds there.

Comment: if  ssh -i $identityfile -p 22 $user@$hostname == True
        then
                echo "Successful"
        else
                echo "Failed to login."
      fi


When I run this I'm getting the error 

Warning: Identity file "/home/ubuntu/Documents/client_server_key.pem" not accessible: No such file or directory.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname "00.00.000.000": Name or service not known
Failed to login.

Comment: Your pem file isn't accessible. That seems like it's out of the scope of this answer.